# Table rows as links from 1 PHP page to another passing information depending on the row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently I am working on a page that using PHP + MySQL loads users and some of their details in a table and there is also a search option that shows the relevant user.
Now to the problem - I want to make every row from the table to act as a link and to take me to another PHP page that will act as a user profile page and will present its information. The information in the 2nd page should depend on the row that was clicked.

Currently using PHP I have the following to present the table

```
<?php
    echo '<table id="userlist" align="center">';
    echo "<tr id=\"tableheader\"><td>" . "Name" . "</td><td>" . "Email" . "</td><td>" . "Phone" . "</td></tr>";
    while ($userDetails = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<tr>
            <td class=\"hide\">" . $userDetails['Username'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $userDetails['Name']  .  "</td>
            <td>" . $userDetails['Email'] .  "</td>
            <td>" . $userDetails['Phone'] .  "</td>
            </tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table>";  ?>
```

Now adding `<a>` tag and making it `display: block;` won't help me as the table will contain lots of users.

Sessions might be useful if you can assign the username to a session variable at the moment of the click and at the same time load another PHP page to use the session variable otherwise if it assigns the session variables at the start when its loading the table it will require array but if I use the search option I have set (which sets `display:none;` to unmatched rows) this might also interfere with the process and end up showing the wrong user.

Tried also AJAX(new to it) but seems I can't figure out how exactly to work with it and how to set up the table as to be able to pass the necessary information.

Comment: and why can you not add an href into each as a link with get parameters?

Comment: Because it wont pass any data  to the other page, unless you can think of a way?

Comment: This is basically what GET variables are for. Just generate an `a` element with a link to the page using [GET variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be looking at this the wrong way. I'm assuming you have a primary key for each row in your user table, and I'll assume that it's called "id." You can adjust the following code accordingly if that's not the case.

```
while ($userDetails = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<tr>
        <td><a href=\"profile.php?id=" . $userDetails['id'] . "\">". $userDetails['Username'] . "</a></td>
        <td>" . $userDetails['Name']  .  "</td>
        <td>" . $userDetails['Email'] .  "</td>
        <td>" . $userDetails['Phone'] .  "</td>
        </tr>";  
}
```

Now, when you get to profile.php, you'll be able to access that user id like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id')
$sth->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You don't need to pass the entire user object from one page to the other, just some piece of data that lets the next script identify the data you're trying to access.

You would only need AJAX if you wanted to do all of this behind the scenes, but you would still probably use a URL parameter and $_GET in your processing script.

Answer (score 0):

Use a $_GET to send the data to the other php page.

So in your current page do this to create a link to your user profile page

```
echo "<td><a href='page.php?u=".$userDetails['Username']."'>View User</a>";
```

on the user profile page, get their username you just passed in the link like so:

```
<?php
   $username = $_GET['u'];
?>
```

Your URL will look like : page?u=jdoe

You can send multiple parameters by using a &

```
page.php?u=jdoe&type=cat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the user ID with GET and on the profile page you can run a new MySql request to get the user details with given ID.

So the profile link will be like:

```
/profile.php?user=15
```

And in profile.php get the user ID with:

```
 $_GET['user']
```

And use that user ID for a MySQL request to get all the user details from database.

This way you will not have a very long URL.